# ExtJS 6 - Select default row on a grid after fully loaded from binds?

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, grid, extjs6

Thanks in advance for your help...

I am having a hard time, trying to select the first row from an ExtJS 6 Grid, after it's fully loaded from it's binds!

I have tried several events like, load, boxready, afterrender, etc... But none seems to do the trick!

**What event should i use to select a row from the grid after the grid has loaded all records from the binds?**

Any examples would be great on how to do this.

Here is my grid:

```
        {
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        cls: 'user-grid',
        routeId: 'languages',
        itemId: 'mainGrid',
        reference: 'mainGrid',
        bind: '{languages}',
        scrollable: false,
        tbar: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'foo',
                toolTip: 'bar',
                iconCls: 'x-fa fa-plus',
                handler: 'onFooClick'
            }
        ],

        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true,
            getRowClass: function(record) {
                var rowCls ='';
                if (record.get('is_active') === false) {
                    rowCls = 'inactive-row';
                }

                if (record.get('is_system') === true) {
                    rowCls = 'system-row';
                }
                return rowCls;
            }
        },

        columns: {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 40,
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    text: 'id',
                    toolTip: 'the id'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    cls: 'content-column',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    text: 'name',
                    toolTip: 'the name'
                    flex: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                dock: 'bottom',
                itemId: 'userPaginationToolbar',
                reference: 'userPaginationToolbar',
                displayInfo: true,
                bind: '{languages}'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As @bullettrain mentioned in a comment, you can listen for an event on the store and select the grid's first record in the event handler:

```
refresh: function (store, eOpts) {
    if (store.count() && !grid.selModel.hasSelection()) {
        grid.selModel.select(0);
    }
}
```

In the event handler you can ensure that the store contains some records using `store.count()` and that the user has not already selected a row `!grid.selModel.hasSelection()`.

According to the Sencha docs, the [load](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-load) event

> Fires whenever the store reads data from a remote data source

and the [refresh](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#event-refresh) event

> Fires when the data cache has changed in a bulk manner

Either of these events could work depending on how you are adding data to the store.

See fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vf5) for an example.

Comment: Hi thank you for you comment, however, i dont quite get it yet. Look at this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vgc if you use the store on the grid, it works fine, if you use the *bind* config the grid row does not get selected! Is it such a great idea to use the binds anyway?

Comment: @CrazyMenConnected That's because the store is not yet bound to the grid. In your fiddle, if you `console.log(grid.getStore())` before setting the selection, you will see that it logs the default ext empty store. Data binding is a double–edged sword!

Comment: Ok, the store is not yet bound... So what event, or what can i do to acomplish the same behavior?

Comment: @CrazyMenConnected For now, I use the [storechange](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.chart.AbstractChart.html#event-storechange) event. In the docs, it's documented as fired by charts only, I found that it also fired by grids and combos.

Answer (score -1):

Try: yourGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].setStyle().

Comment: And on what event should i place that code? I think that is the main issue here, i cant find an even that is fired after the grid has loaded all the binded records!

Comment: ok, try using load event, but call it on your store which is the one bringing in your records for the grid:  store.on('load', function(){
    //do something
});